# Multiple Null Foreign keys group join error in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this following LINQ statement which giving the following error

> Type inference failed in the call to Group join

```
var EmployeeList = (from requestemployee in _context.BulkTransportRequestEmployees
                            join request in _context.BulkTransportRequests on requestemployee.BulkRequestBulkRequestId equals request.BulkRequestId
                            join employee in _context.Employees on requestemployee.EmployeeEmployeeId equals employee.EmployeeId
                            join deptemp in _context.EmployeeDepartments on employee.EmployeeId equals deptemp.EmployeeEmployeeId
                            join dept in _context.Departments on deptemp.DepartmentDepartmentId equals dept.DepartmentId
                            //Error is in here
                            join routepath in _context.RootPaths on new { Key1 = requestemployee.CityCityId, Key2 =  requestemployee.RootRootId } equals new { Key1 = routepath.CityId, Key2 = routepath.RootId } into join_routepath
                            from routepath in join_routepath.DefaultIfEmpty()

                            join route in _context.Roots on routepath.RootId equals route.RootId
                            join destination in _context.Cities on routepath.CityId equals destination.CityId
                            join pass in _context.TransportPasses on employee.EmployeeId equals pass.IssuedToEmployeeId into join_employee_pass
                            from pass in join_employee_pass.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where deptemp.IsDefaultDepartment == true && 
                            request.RequestType == 1 &&
                            employee.EmployeeType == emptype &&
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(request.TripDateAndTime) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(FromDate) &&
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(request.TripDateAndTime) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ToDate) &&
                            (pass.IsHold == true || pass.IsCanceled == true || pass.IssuedDate == null || pass.PassType == 1)
                            group new { employee, request, routepath } by new
                            {
                                dept.DepartmentName,
                                employee.EmployeeId,
                                employee.EmpCode,
                                employee.EmployeeCallingName,
                                employee.EmployeeSurname,
                                employee.NameWithInitials

                            } into g
                            select new
                            {

                                g.Key.EmployeeId,
                                g.Key.EmpCode,
                                Employee = g.Key.EmployeeCallingName + " - " + g.Key.NameWithInitials,
                                g.Key.DepartmentName
                            }).ToList();
```

requestemployee keys are nullable types. So how could I establish this group join without error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Just write down for others' use.

because `requestemployee.CityCityId`and`requestemployee.RootRootId` keys are nullable I need to change `routepath.CityId` and `routepath.RootId` also to accept null as follow

```
join routepath in _context.RootPaths on new { Key1 = requestemployee.CityCityId, Key2 = requestemployee.RootRootId } equals new { Key1 = (int?)routepath.CityId, Key2 = (int?)routepath.RootId } into join_routepath
from routepath in join_routepath.DefaultIfEmpty()
```